# Accessing data stored in a Llist

Tags: c++, list, vector

I’m pretty new to C++ and I am looking for some help with how I can access data store in a list. I am currently storing the move a player make which are represented by a vector of vectors in a list.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > move1;

std::vector<std::vector<int> > move2;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > move3;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > move4;

    std::list<vector<vector<int>>> moveList;

void PuzzleBoard::NextPossibleMove()
{
    //assigns the current board state to a temp hold var
    nextBoard = board;

    //A switch statement to attempt to move in each direction once
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 1: {
            //attempts to move zero up
            MoveZero(1, userPS);

            //stores the board after the move
            move1 = board;


            //Add the vector of vectors move1 to the list variable moveList
            moveList.push_back(move1);


            //Resets the board to its original state
            board = nextBoard;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            //attempts to move zero down
            MoveZero(2, userPS);

            //stores the board after the move
            move2 = board;


            //Add the vector of vectors move2 to the list variable moveList
            moveList.push_back(move2);


            //Resets the board to its original state
            board = nextBoard;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            //attempts to move zero left
            MoveZero(3, userPS);

            //stores the board after the move
            move3 = board;


            //Add the vector of vectors move3 to the list variable moveList
            moveList.push_back(move3);


            //Resets the board to its original state
            board = nextBoard;
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            //attempts to move zero right
            MoveZero(4, userPS);

            //stores the board after the move
            move4 = board;


            //Add the vector of vectors move4 to the list variable moveList
            moveList.push_back(move4);



            //Resets the board to its original state
            board = nextBoard;
            break;
        }
        {
        default:
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I have the vector of vectors move in the list I don’t know how to access them. 
I tried this:

```
void PuzzleBoard::PrintMovesFromList()
{
    for (std::list<int>::iterator iter = moveList.begin(); iter < moveList.end(); iter++) {

        cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

However, it says moveList does not have a conversion type to do it this way. 
I also tried this:

```
void PuzzleBoard::PrintMovesFromList()
{
    for (std::list<vector<vector<int>>>::iterator iter = moveList.begin(); iter < moveList.end(); iter++) {

        cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

However, it says there is no operator matches for <.

Basically, I want to store the moves the player makes (which will always be represented as a vector of vectors) in a list and after the game is over I want to access the vector of vectors stored in the list to print them to the screen. I have searched several site about using lists, however I haven’t come a crossed any site giving an example of what I am trying to do. Can anyone point me in the right direction or explain how I can access the stored data in the manner I am trying to?
Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Change `iter < moveList.end();` to `iter != moveList.end();`

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` iterators are not random access iterators. Only random access operators can be ordered like that.

`std::list` iterators can only be compared for equality:

```
for (std::list<int>::iterator iter = moveList.begin();
         iter != moveList.end(); iter++) {
```

However, since you're "new to C++" you should really be learning how to iterate over a container using new language features from the current C++ standard:

```
for (const auto &value:moveList)
      cout << value << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you Sam I was able to get it working once you pointed out my mistake. I will look into the documentation for the currn=ent C++ standard. Thanks again.